# Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I try to execute this small code, I am getting this error. Could someone please help me to sort it out.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Student_details11 
(
    ROLL_NO Int,
    NAME VARCHAR(25),
    ADDRESS VARCHAR(25),
    PHONE Int,
    AGE Int
);

INSERT INTO Student_details11 (ROLL_NO, NAME, ADDRESS, PHONE, AGE) 
VALUES (1, 'Ram', 'Delhi', 9415536635, 24)
```

Comment: Phone should probably be a text field (e.g., varchar(15)) rather than an int. Int type fields often max out at 2147483647 (~2 billion) whereas the phone is larger (over 9 billion). If it must be numerical, consider other types e.g. bigint

Comment: A phone "number" is not typically stored as a number. It can have plus sign, dashes, parenthesis and spaces. Stores it as a `VARCHAR(20)`. For example, consider the phone `+421 (282)-45-23 ext. 4101`.

Comment: Please review https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: My preference would be to store phone numbers with separate columns for the country code, area code, number and extension and disallow the entry of anything other than numerals. Allowing operators to enter anything else inevitably results in a complete mess of inconsistency.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Microsoft documentation on the `int` data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql), it only supports values between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647, while you are trying to insert a value of 9,415,536,635, which is outside of this range.

If the value really needs to be numeric, consider using `bigint`:

```
create table #Student_details11 
(
    ROLL_NO int,
    [NAME] varchar(25),
    [ADDRESS] varchar(25),
    PHONE int,
    AGE int
)
```

However, if the `PHONE` column is intended to store a phone number, you'd probably be better using a text-type such as `varchar` as suggested in the comments:

```
create table #Student_details11 
(
    ROLL_NO int,
    [NAME] varchar(25),
    [ADDRESS] varchar(25),
    PHONE varchar(10),
    AGE int
)
```